# solace - Failover connection

Tags: c#, .net, failover, solace, solace-mq

I am using solace topic to send my messages, and the session property in host has multiple comma separated IPs: `(ip1:port1,ip2:port2)`. So in case of `failover`, how do I know which IP I have connected to?

Answer (score 0):

After a client has connected or reconnected, you can identify which broker you have connected to by querying the VirtualRouterName session property:
https://docs.solace.com/API-Developer-Online-Ref-Documentation/net/html/53b05ea7-ce0b-4c77-dde7-0807274c1c44.htm